# How to read large video files in JavaScript using FileReader?

Tags: javascript, html, video, filereader

I want the user of my website to be able to upload a potentially large video file to it using HTML‘s file input. The video should than be processed and played locally in the user‘s browser.

```
let fileInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
fileInput.setAttribute("type", "file");
fileInput.onChange = onFileSelected;
```

To read the video file uploaded by the user, I wanted to use a `File Reader` like this:

```
function onFileSelected(e) {
  // The file uploaded by the user:
  let file = e.target.files[0];

  // Create a file reader:
  let reader = new  FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    video.src = e.target.result;
  }
}
```

However, when I uploaded really large video files (≈300 MB), `e.target.result` was not a URI to the video file, like I expected, but an empty string.

How can I read very large video files using `File Reader` in JavaScript?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `FileReader` class in JavaScript contains [multiple methods to read files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

- `readAsText()`: This reads a file and returns its content as text. Suitable for small text files.
- `readAsBinaryString()`: This reads a file and returns its content as a binary string. Suitable for small files of any type.
- `readAsDataURL()`: This reads a file and returns a Data URL referencing it. This is inefficient for large files as the file is loaded into memory as a whole before being processed.
- `readAsArrayBuffer()`: This reads a file and returns an `ArrayBuffer` containing the input file 'chopped up in smaller pieces'. This works for very large files, too.

In the question, the `readAsDataURL()` method is used as it is usually most convenient. However, for very large video files (and very large files in general) it does not work for the reason described above leading to an empty result. Instead, you should use `readAsArrayBuffer()`:

```
let reader = new  FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Now, the file reader returns an `ArrayBuffer` after loading the file. In order to be able to show the video in HTML, we have to convert this buffer to a blob, that can then give us a URL to the video file:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  // The file reader gives us an ArrayBuffer:
  let buffer = e.target.result;

  // We have to convert the buffer to a blob:
  let videoBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)], { type: 'video/mp4' });

  // The blob gives us a URL to the video file:
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

  video.src = url;
}
```