# problem with preview large video size in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want to upload video in server but befor that i need preview that file to user, i have a problem for doing that .

when i uploaded the small video it worked find but when i need upload the large video and need to preview it , the page is carshed .

i write this code :

```
    ConvertFileToAddress(event): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            resolve(e.target['result']);
        };
    });
}
```

**how can i solve  this problem ?**

Comment: Does it crash on the upload? And if so, how do you upload this..?

Comment: @MikeOne no . when i need to preview it in the page before upload it

Comment: Right. Using DataUrl is probably not going to work. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61012790/how-to-read-large-video-files-in-javascript-using-filereader

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer .

i change my code to this :

```
onSelectedFile(ev) {
  let file = ev.target.files[0];
  var URL = window.URL;
  this.src = 
  this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
  this.fileBinary.emit(file)
}
```

and its worked . . .