# I got this error in my console: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting this error when I try to create a JS function where users can preview their files before submit: **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.** I want to create a JS function similar to Twitter where users can preview their image/video files before posting it. But I'm using two inputs instead of one as I'm not sure how it works with only one input. So far, only image files are working. This is the relevant code in my HTML:

```html
          <textarea id="autoresizing" name="post"></textarea>

          <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
            <img src="" class="image-preview__image">
          </div>

          <div class="video-preview" id="videoPreview">
            <video controls loop autoplay muted class="video-preview__video" id="video" src=""></video>
          </div>

          <br>
          <label for="inpFile"><img id="image_icon" src="images/image_icon.png"></label>
          <input id="inpFile" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="image/*">
          <label for="inpFile2"><img id="video_icon" src="images/video_icon.png"></label>
          <input id="inpFile2" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="video/*">

          <input id="post_button" type="submit" value="Post" style="margin:5px;">
```

This is the JS function:

```js
//preview image in textarea
  const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
  const previewContainer = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
  const previewImage = previewContainer.querySelector(".image-preview__image");

  inpFile.addEventListener("change", function() {
    const file = this.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      previewContainer.style.display = "block";
      previewImage.style.display = "block";

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        previewImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      previewImage.style.display = null;
      previewImage.setAttribute("src", "");
    }
  });

  // preview video in textarea
  const inpFile2 = document.getElementById('inpFile2');
  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  const previewVideoContainer = document.getElementById("videoPreview");
  const previewVideo = previewVideoContainer.querySelector(".video-preview__video");
  const videoSource = document.createElement('source');

  inpFile2.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const file = this.files[0];

    if (file) {

      const reader = new FileReader();

      previewVideoContainer.style.display = "block";

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        videoSource.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        video.appendChild(videoSource);
        video.load();
        video.play();
      };

      reader.onprogress = function(e) {
        console.log('progress: ', Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      previewVideoContainer.style.display = null;
      previewVideoContainer.setAttribute("src", "");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Why use a filereader in this case? Wouldn't it be fine to just set the src of the video element, listen for the load event and then start the video (if that is the purpose).

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. What do you suggest I should do in this case? What should I replace filereader with?

Comment: I removed video.play(); from the reader.onload function and now the error's not showing. But I still can't preview video files. I can only preview image files

Comment: OK, you need to use the Filereader. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using this video: https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-videos/flower.webm
The filereader for the video has to use `readAsArrayBuffer()` like suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61012791/322084

```js
//preview image in textarea
const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
const previewContainer = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
const previewImage = previewContainer.querySelector(".image-preview__image");

inpFile.addEventListener("change", e => {
  let file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    previewContainer.style.display = "block";
    previewImage.style.display = "block";

    reader.addEventListener("load", e => {
      previewImage.src = e.target.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    previewImage.style.display = "none";
    previewImage.src = "";
  }
});

// preview video in textarea
const inpFile2 = document.getElementById('inpFile2');
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const previewVideoContainer = document.getElementById("videoPreview");
const previewVideo = previewVideoContainer.querySelector(".video-preview__video");
const videoSource = document.createElement('source');

inpFile2.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file) {

    let reader = new FileReader();

    previewVideoContainer.style.display = "block";

    reader.addEventListener("load", e => {
      let buffer = e.target.result;

      let videoBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(buffer)], {
        type: e.target.filetype
      });

      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

      video.src = url;
      video.play();
    });

    reader.addEventListener("progress", e => {
      console.log('progress: ', Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
    });

    reader.filetype = file.type;
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  } else {
    previewVideoContainer.style.display = null;
    previewVideoContainer.src = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="autoresizing" name="post"></textarea>

<div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img src="" class="image-preview__image">
</div>

<div class="video-preview" id="videoPreview">
  <video controls loop autoplay muted class="video-preview__video" id="video"></video>
</div>

<br>
<label for="inpFile"><img id="image_icon" src="images/image_icon.png"></label>
<input id="inpFile" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="image/*">
<label for="inpFile2"><img id="video_icon" src="images/video_icon.png"></label>
<input id="inpFile2" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="video/*">

<input id="post_button" type="submit" value="Post" style="margin:5px;">
```

#### UPDATE

In the following I striped out all the functionality except when selecting an image the video select should be disabled and vice versa. I went for an old-school fieldset that can disable all its children. Alternatively you can just disable the input element itself.

```js
const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");

inpFile.addEventListener("change", e => {
  let file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file) {
    e.target.form.video.disabled = true;
  }
});

const inpFile2 = document.getElementById('inpFile2');

inpFile2.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];

  if (file) {
    e.target.form.image.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```css
fieldset:disabled label {
  opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
<fieldset name="image">
  <legend>Pick an image</legend>
  <label for="inpFile"><img id="image_icon" src="images/image_icon.png"></label>
  <input id="inpFile" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="image/*">
</fieldset>
<fieldset name="video">
  <legend>Pick a video</legend>
  <label for="inpFile2"><img id="video_icon" src="images/video_icon.png"></label>
  <input id="inpFile2" type="file" name="file" style="display:none;" accept="video/*">
</fieldset>
<input id="post_button" type="submit" value="Post" style="margin:5px;">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This works perfectly. If you have time, could you help me on another issue? How do I disable the video input when a user has already selected an image to preview and vice versa? I would really appreciate your help on this but if you don't have the time, I'd totally understand.

Comment: @rustyrice23 I updated my answer. The last snippet has the functionality that you requested.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far that worked really well. Just one problem. After removing an image file from preview, it's not letting me access to video input. Do you have a solution to this? Is there a way to implement a cancel button to the top right corner of an image/video so users can press that and it will automatically remove the preview?